# How to give a better Y axis label / scale in d3 chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, axis, linechart

I have a real time animated line chart.

Y axis domain will be updated every time interval based on incoming max data

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(data)]);
```

Then I update the Y axis label as per below

```
svg.selectAll("g.y.axis")
.interrupt()
.transition()
.duration(duration)
.ease("linear")
.call(y.axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left"));
```

The **width** of the line chart is small and I set it at **90**

Therefore the label will looks a bit weird due to lack of space as shown below:

**Picture 1:**

[image: equal spacing]

and also look like this

**Picture 2:**

[image: equal spacing]

**Is there any option to scale the label better?**

Example in **Picture 1** the label for interval can be updated as `[0, 2, 4, 6, ... 10, 12]` instead of `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ... 10, 11, 12]`

Example in **Picture 2** the label for interval can be updated as `[0, 4, 8, 12, ... 20, 24]` instead of `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8 ... 20, 22, 24]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`ticks(number)`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#ticks) method on the axis to tell it to draw fewer ticks; the default is to draw approximately 10 ticks.  The actual number of ticks is adjusted to get round-number intervals between tick values, which is why you were getting 12 ticks using the default behaviour.

For your case you want to use

```
y.axis = d3.svg.axis().ticks(6).scale(y).orient("left")
```